# Closure appending array

Tags: javascript

I am learning about closures and have to make a function that directly modifies myArray, and then the returned function returns the value of myArray.

Why does this generate the error "expandedArray is not defined"?

```
function expandArray() {
    let myArray = [1, 1, 1];

    return function(addToArray) {
        myArray.push(addToArray);
        return myArray;
    };
}
let result = expandedArray();
result(1);
```

The exampled I am provided is ;

```
function outerFunction() {
  let num1 = 5;

  return function(num2) {
    console.log(num1 + num2);
  };
}
let result = outerFunction();
result(10); //returns 15
```

Comment: your function is named `expandArray`, not `expandedArray`

Comment: Yup, that was it :(

Comment: `result(10); //returns 15`. The comment is wrong, it outputs 15 to the console it does not return `15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `expandedArray` to `expandArray` or vice-versa.

```js
function expandArray() {
    let myArray = [1, 1, 1];

    return function(addToArray) {
        myArray.push(addToArray);
        return myArray;
    };
}
let result = expandArray();
result(1);
```